# Supported Android devices 0 devices (6248 removed)

Tags: android, eclipse

I uploaded my apk on google play store without some libraries and then added this libraries to my apk then tried to upload it again but google play says that :
Supported Android devices 0 devices (6248 removed)
Native platforms getLibs.ps1, getLibs.sh, gson-2.2.2.jar 
and this the difference between last apk and the current apk.
I tried a lot of things but it didn't work ..

Comment: Post a lot more informations about your `AndroidManifest.xml` and your natives libraries please.

Answer (score 0):

Unsupported devices usually occur because certain requirements are not met.

These requirements are specified in the manifest e.g. requires Camera, internet, storage card access, Screen sizes.

```
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  ... ETC
```

As you state, It worked fine before you added the libraries.

Check the requirements specified in the libraries. Make sure the requirements aren't conflicting with the requirements of your app or the other libraries.